# SQL Promote child in Hierarchical structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query that allows me to promote children's level a hierarchical table, without result.
below the example table:

[image]

the solution I would like to apply is that if a child is a child of a code starting with 'NO_' they must be linked to the higher-level father who does not start with 'NO_'.
example:

[image]

I've tried some solutions, such as using cte or update from join, without getting a result, and can I have support?

thx

update 1

delete/replace column is note on img,
I've been trying to apply solutions like that:

```
WITH CHILD (PARENT,CHILD)
AS
(select B.PARENT,B.CHILD
from BOM B
where B.CHILD like 'NO_%')

Select * from CHILD


WITH PARENT (PARENT,CHILD)
AS
(SELECT B.PARENT,B.CHILD
    FROM BOM B
    where B.PARENT like 'NO_%')

select * from PARENT
```

and then apply an update

Comment: Share the attempts you made.

Comment: Where does this delete/replace column come from?

Comment: delete/replace column is note on img,I've been trying to apply solutions like that:  
    WITH CHILD (PARENT,CHILD)
AS
(select B.CODICE_PADRE,B.CODICE_FIGLIO
from DBWORKS2IDEALE_BOM B
where B.CODICE_FIGLIO like 'NO_%')

Select * from CHILD


WITH PARENT (PARENT,CHILD)
AS
(SELECT B.PARENT,B.CHILD
 FROM DBWORKS2IDEALE_BOM B
 where B.CODICE_PADRE like 'NO_')

select * from PARENT       and then apply an update

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and usable sample data is much more helpful than a picture of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CTE recursive to identify the New Parent. First you select the non 'NO_' children who's parents are 'NO_'. From them you have to move up on the hierarchy, until you found a non 'NO_' parent. For this, I used an extra column NEW_PARENT_FOUND.

Here is the query, which can easily transformed to an update.

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
declare @vBOM table (PARENT varchar(20), CHILD varchar(20))
insert into @vBOM( PARENT, CHILD )
values
    ('C002584', 'NO_CRT874')
    , ('NO_CRT874', 'F8745')
    , ('NO_CRT874', 'IY845')
    , ('NO_CRT874', 'YRF522')
    , ('C002584', 'NO_UYTRR')
    , ('NO_UYTRR', 'NO_UYT953')
    , ('NO_UYT953', 'FEWF845')
    , ('C002584', '95659I')
    , ('C002584', '84666E')


; with cteNewParent as
    (select B.CHILD, B.PARENT NEW_PARENT, 0 NEW_PARENT_FOUND 
    from @vBOM B 
    where B.CHILD not like 'NO_%' and B.PARENT like 'NO_%'
    union all
    select NP.CHILD, B.PARENT NEW_PARENT, iif(NP.CHILD not like 'NO_%' and B.PARENT not like 'NO_%', 1, 0) NEW_PARENT_FOUND
    from cteNewParent NP inner join @vBOM B on B.CHILD = NP.NEW_PARENT
    where NP.NEW_PARENT_FOUND = 0 
    )
select NP.CHILD, NP.NEW_PARENT, NP.NEW_PARENT_FOUND, B.PARENT, B.CHILD
from cteNewParent NP inner join @vBOM B on B.CHILD = NP.CHILD
where NP.NEW_PARENT_FOUND = 1
```